# Try to update the user data seeing some time fetching issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch the user based on their id but can't sometimes I get the user but it is like the state is preserving the values if I try to get another user value but I still saw the previous user data. Hey anyone please help me I am stuck here for hours now.

here is the image of my users list[image]

### here is an update

I went to my network tab and saw that
I get the user Based on their users but I see the value in fields until I click on my first user in the shown list which is shown in fields then again If click the next user I still see the first user details so it definitely not API issue in my state problem please help me to fix this.

### EditUser.tsx

```
const UpdateUser = ({ setUsers, id }) => {
    const animatedComponents = makeAnimated();
    const [rolesData, setRolesData] = useState([]);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [role, setRole] = useState("");
    const [job_preference, setJobPreference] =
        useState([]);
    const [multiSelect, setMultiSelect] = useState(
        []
    );

    const fetchDataBasedOnID = async (id) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/user/${id}`
    );

    getDataOfMultiSelect(data);
};

const getDataOfMultiSelect = (data) => {
    const result = states.filter((state) =>
        data.job_preference.includes(state.value)
    );

    setMultiSelect(result);
    setName(data.name);
    setEmail(data.email);
    setRole(data.role);
};

    const resetFields = () => {
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setMultiSelect("");
        setRole("");
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        handleRoles();
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { data } = await axios.put(
            `/api/user/${id}`,
            {
                name,
                email,
                role,
                job_preference,
            }
        );
        toast.success("User updated successfully");
        usersList();
        resetFields();
    };

    return (
        <>
            {/* Button trigger modal */}
            <div>
                <button
                    type='button'
                    onClick={() => fetchDataBasedOnID(id)}
                    className='btn btn-warning'
                    data-bs-toggle='modal'
                    data-bs-target='#updateModal'>
                    <BiEdit />
                </button>
            </div>

            {/* Modal */}
            <div
                className='modal fade'
                id='updateModal'
                tabIndex='-1'
                aria-hidden='true'>
                <div className='modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered'>
                    <div className='modal-content'>
                        <div className='modal-header'>
                            <h1
                                className='modal-title fs-5'
                                id='exampleModalLabel'>
                                Update User
                            </h1>
                            <button
                                type='button'
                                className='btn-close'
                                data-bs-dismiss='modal'
                                aria-label='Close'></button>
                        </div>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div className='modal-body'>
                                <div className='mb-3'>
                                    <label className='form-label'>
                                        Name
                                    </label>
                                    <input
                                        type='text'
                                        value={name}
                                        onChange={(e) =>
                                            setName(e.target.value)
                                        }
                                        required
                                        className='form-control'
                                        placeholder='John Doe'
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className='mb-3'>
                                    <label className='form-label'>
                                        Email address
                                    </label>
                                    <input
                                        type='email'
                                        value={email}
                                        required
                                        onChange={(e) =>
                                            setEmail(e.target.value)
                                        }
                                        className='form-control'
                                        placeholder='name@example.com'
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className='mb-3'>
                                    <label className='form-label'>
                                        Role
                                    </label>
                                    <select
                                        className='form-select option'
                                        value={role}
                                        onChange={handleRoleChange}>
                                        <option className='option'>
                                            Select a Role
                                        </option>
                                        {rolesData?.map(
                                            ({ _id, role_name }) => (
                                                <option
                                                    className='option'
                                                    key={_id}
                                                    value={role_name}>
                                                    {role_name}
                                                </option>
                                            )
                                        )}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className='mb-3'>
                                    <label className='form-label'>
                                        Job Preference
                                    </label>
                                    <Select
                                        value={multiSelect}
                                        isMulti
                                        components={
                                            animatedComponents
                                        }
                                        isSearchable
                                        placeholder='Choose any 3 states as job location'
                                        options={states}
                                        onChange={
                                            handleMultiSelectChange
                                        }
                                        isOptionDisabled={() =>
                                            multiSelect.length >= 3
                                        }
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='modal-footer'>
                                <button
                                    type='button'
                                    className='btn btn-secondary'
                                    data-bs-dismiss='modal'>
                                    Close
                                </button>
                                <button
                                    type='submit'
                                    className='btn btn-success'
                                    data-bs-dismiss='modal'>
                                    Save Changes
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default UpdateUser;
```

Comment: maybe you should also add how `id` is being passed ...

Comment: where do you call a function for `click the next user`? that is the key function to check your logic

Comment: @KcH the id passed from users list component because edit user a button which is shown every users data with their id embedded

Comment: @NickVu its is in the jsx because when I click the button it opens a modal you see in the jsx as button onclick

Comment: @KcH Please check the picture you will understand yellow button is the edit button

Comment: log and see if the `id` changes when clicked ?

Comment: @KcH yes i get the different ids and also users data from database the problem I don't see it in my fields

Comment: can you add a runnable sample of same ?

Comment: @KcH should I share some other screenshots or what because I can't get you?

Comment: I mean try to add a runnable sample using codesandbox / stackblitz to debug the issue easily .... it is hard for one to go through all the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249584/discussion-between-dev-dragon-and-kch).